# Running cucumber with scalatest

Tags: scala, cucumber, scalatest, cucumber-jvm

Is there a way to run cucumber from scalatest?

I know running cucumber using junit like below

```
@RunWith(classOf[Cucumber])
@CucumberOptions(features = ..., tags = ...)
class CucumberStarter
```

But I'm not sure how I can run cucumber from scalatest.
I've tried to below, and it run but doesn't seem to respect the `@CucumberOptions`

```
@RunWith(classOf[Cucumber])
@CucumberOptions(features = ..., tags = ...)
class CucumberStarter extends JunitSuite
```

Comment: Afaik there is not. Cucumber-jvm supports JUnit and TestNG. Afaik there is a scala implementation, but it was taken out of the cucumber-jvm project so it will be behind on latest developments.